# Can't justify Blogger's posts by default

Tags: blogger

I want to write justified posts by default, but I haven't managed to do so.

I have approached the problem from two different ways:

- Editing in CSS .post-body to add text-align: justify;. Anything happens.
- Using the option of defining a post template, and using `<div style="text-align: justify;"> </div>`. The code is in the posts, but below whatever I'm writing, i.e., what I writes is not within the `<div>` tag.

So basically my question is, what can I do so every new post is by default like:

```
<div style="text-align:justify;">
my post content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

nevermind, just managed to do so. Instead of just writing

```
<div style="text-align: justify;"> 
</div>
```

I wrote

```
<div style="text-align: justify;"> 
text
</div>
```

This way I can remove `text` and write whatever I want, and it remains within the `<div>`tag.